# Android app for auto calls

Tags: android, ios

I need a free app for Android/IOS which allows user to make auto call. The app you can input your own audio, set phone number and time the calls would made.

Answer (score 1):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) does this and a lot more. It has `Call` action which allows you to `Auto Dial` a number. On newer Android versions or with custom phone call apps it could require help of [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) for the call to go through.

Unfortunately, audio part of it is (almost) impossible simply because Android doesn't allow apps to automatically talk to the other side - see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48659831/7264739) for more details. For obvious security reasons, as that could result in apps abusing permissions and advertising spam/scams whenever you make calls.

You could work around it by using 3rd party device next to the phone, e.g. some speaker, which is connected to a computer. Tasker could then contact the computer through various means (e.g. a HTTP request, IFTTT or an app like [Join](https://joaoapps.com/join/)) and the computer would need to be programmed to play the sound through the speaker. Another option is 2nd phone.